# Has anyone used Polars and Seaborn or Matplotlib together?

Tags: python, types, seaborn, python-polars

Has anyone used a Polars dataframe with Seaborn to graph something? I've been working through a notebook on Kaggle that used Pandas, and I wanted to refactor it to Polars.

The dataframe I'm working with looks like this:

| PassengerID (i64) | Survived (i64) | Pclass (i64) | Name (str) | ... | Ticket (str) | Fare (f64) | Cabin (str) | Embarked (str) | Age (f64) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 0 | 3 | your name here | ... | A/5 21171 | 7.25 | null | S | 24 |
| ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... |

Kaggle has me making a histogram with the following code:

```
g = sns.FacetGrid(train_df, col='Survived')
g.map(plt.hist, 'Age', bins=20)
```

When I run these two lines I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/seaborn/axisgrid.py", line 678, in map
    for (row_i, col_j, hue_k), data_ijk in self.facet_data():
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/seaborn/axisgrid.py", line 632, in facet_data
    data_ijk = data[row & col & hue & self._not_na]
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/polars/internals/series/series.py", line 906, in __array_ufunc__
    args.append(arg.view(ignore_nulls=True))
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/polars/internals/series/series.py", line 2680, in view
    ptr_type = dtype_to_ctype(self.dtype)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/polars/datatypes.py", line 550, in dtype_to_ctype
    raise NotImplementedError(
NotImplementedError: Conversion of polars data type <class 'polars.datatypes.Boolean'> to C-type not implemented.
```

I don't have any boolean datatypes in my dataframe, so I'm not sure what to do about this error. Any ideas?

Comment: It is not recommended to directly use [`sns.FacetGrid`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.FacetGrid.html). The correct methods are `ax = sns.histplot(data=train_df.to_pandas(), x='Age', col='Survived', bins=20)` or `g = sns.displot(data=train_df.to_pandas(), x='Age', col='Survived', bins=20)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

seaborn doesn't accept a polars dataframe as an input.  You just have to use `to_pandas()`

so change `g = sns.FacetGrid(train_df, col='Survived')` to

```
g = sns.FacetGrid(train_df.to_pandas(), col='Survived')
```

Answer (score 4):

Now, Seaborn supports DataFrame objects from libraries other than pandas (e.g. polars) using Dataframe Exchange Protocol.

Check it out [here](https://seaborn.pydata.org/whatsnew/v0.13.0.html#support-for-alternate-dataframe-libraries).